# Converting matlab polar plot into x,y plot

Tags: matlab, polar-coordinates

I have data which produces a polar plot

[image]

where I want to obtain the ratio of the x and y data points (x/y) at each angle then plot the ratio (x/y) versus the angle theta (0,...,360). What is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you add a pseudo code to reproduce that polar plot? Usually the output of a plot can have the metadata (x,y or r and angle, etc) of the generated plot. The metadata can be used to get wat you are looking.

Comment: did you have the data? Write the program you wrote to produce this figure, it can be modified to produce what you want

Comment: I don't understand...I have rho and theta data, I simply use polarplot(theta,rho) to obtain the plot.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the rho and theta coordinates for each data point in the plot, you can easily obtain the (x,y) coordinates.

Assuming your polar coordinates are stored in two separate vectors of the same length, 'rho' and 'theta', you could use the following code to extract the respective x and y coordinates:

```
% theta is expressed in radians
x = rho .* cos(theta) ;
y = rho .* sin(theta) ;
```

and then compute the ratio as follows:

```
x_over_y = x ./ y ;
```

Alternatively, you could do everything in one step, like so:

```
% theta is expressed in radians
x_over_y = (rho .* cos(theta)) ./ (rho .* sin(theta)) ;
```

Once you have x_over_y, you can plot it against the theta values:

```
% theta is expressed in radians
plot(theta*180/pi, x_over_y) ;
```